# Error: spawn node ENOENT

Tags: javascript, express, electron

I'm working on my Electron app with Express server and when I build it with electron-packager, I get an error.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
```

here is my main.js where child process is called

```
const cp = require('child_process'); 
let instance = cp.spawn('node',['./app.js']);

var electron = require('electron');

var browserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var app = electron.app;

app.on('ready', function(){

// appWindow
    var appWindow;
    appWindow = new browserWindow({
        width:1120,
        height:620,
        webPreferences: {
            plugins: true
        },
        icon: __dirname + '/public/icon/icon.png' 
    });
    appWindow.loadURL('file://' +__dirname + '/public/prva.html');

    //appWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
});

// close app after all windows are closed
    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})
```

Does anyone know solution for this error?

Comment: you need to ad full file path most probably.

Comment: How can I get full path of app.js file?

Comment: Replace ./app.js  with process.cwd()+'app.js'

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt work. I updated code with let instance = cp.spawn('node',[process.cwd()+'app.js']); but still when I package my app, get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a problem with your app.js script. You should hook onto some of the event listeners to understand what's really going on. There's an error, exit, close, disconnect, and message events you can listen for. You can also hook onto a number of other things such as the stdin, stdout, stderr as well. Checkout the documentation for the different events, hook onto all of them and output some information and you should be able to track down the issue.

You should also check to see if your express services runs properly directly from the command line rather than from within this Electron app. If it does then you've likely got a path wrong. This could be either that child_process cannot find the "node" application to run, or it can't find your startup script. In either case, you can use the `path` module to build up the correct path.